# C# ASP.Net - Javascript confirm

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a popup with the buttons yes or no,and based in what the client select,call a different Method.My code is like this at the moment:

```
User directBoss = new UserManager().GetUserDirectBossByEDV(colaboradorEDV, out objStatus);
                if (directBoss != null)
                {
                    string message = directBoss.Name;
                    JavascriptCall("confirm('O GESTOR CORRETO DO COLABORADOR " + nomeClic + " É O GESTOR " + message + ",DESEJA CONFIRMAR A ALTERAÇÃO?')");
                }
```

I want something like this,is it possible:?

```
User directBoss = new UserManager().GetUserDirectBossByEDV(colaboradorEDV, out objStatus);

                    string message = directBoss.Name;
                    JavascriptCall("confirm('O GESTOR CORRETO DO COLABORADOR " + nomeClic + " É O GESTOR " + message + ",DESEJA CONFIRMAR A ALTERAÇÃO?')");

if (confirm == yes){
AssemblyCorrectPromoter();
}
else{
AssemblyPromoter();
}
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server-side and client-side.  Server-side is everything that happens on the server (e.g. ASP, ASP.NET, PHP) that is used to create the HTML that is sent to the browser. It also deals with the information that is returned by the browser when the user submits stuff back (the post-back).  Client-side is everything that happens on the browser once the HTML has been received, or when user does something on the page like clicking an element.  You are trying to mix the two and it won't work.  You need to look at something like AJAX or SignalR

Comment: If its asp button you can use OnClientClick to call the javascript confirmation and on yes make the method call..

Comment: I found something similar in windows Forms:
DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("TEST",
MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

Comment: Is there a way to use the result1 in similar way in web application?

Comment: @ViniciusCano - examples for windows forms are **not** applicable to web applications/web forms.  They require completely different methodologies.  If you can't understand that, then you need to go back to the **very start** and learn exactly how ASP.NET works